# How to only allow registered users to access my WordPress site

Tags: php, wordpress

I have used the password protect but its no good, I want the users in my users table to only access my wordpress site. Is there a plugin I can use or a go around to this.If anyone visits the site they are forced to login or taken to the wp-login which when successful will take the user to the website. Is there a way.

Comment: Your question will probably get closed, as it's asking for a recommendation, not coding help.  There are plugins that do what you need - https://wordpress.org/plugins/private-only/ for example

Comment: I believe http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ is a more suitable place to post that question, which will give you better answers

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is a way.

```
<?php if(!is_user_logged_in()){wp_redirect( 'http://www.your-blog.com/wp-login' ); exit;}?>
```

Put the above code on top of everything in your theme's header.php